# Is the system with no central storage more secure?

Tags: database, distributed-system

Consider a distributed system S that consists of several processing nodes (N1, N2, N3, ...) and spans the geographical boundaries.

S -> {N1, N2, N3, N4 ...}   N is more than 1000.

now consider that each node maintains its own cache for storage. Whatever enters system is processed and output is returned while any information is stored only in Cache with no central database/ storage.

Is S technically more secure from hacking since there is no single point where storage is available hacker cannot really target all N nodes to get pieces of data, combine these pieces and create useful information.

Comment: If a hacker can't get useful information, how can a genuine user get useful information?

Comment: Generally, if you can hack one node, you can probably hack all others too.

Comment: @Pieter B. hacker gains access to a certain piece information through stealth not using the regular process that system implements but by loopholes, flaws and backdoors. That's another thing if the genuine user has mal intentions but usually genuine user would request and initiate processes of the system in way that is intended and not try to exploit loopholes or flaws if any.

Comment: No, a hacker could also use social engineering techniques to impersonate a legitimate user. Your definition of "hacker" is dangerously strict.

Comment: Why 2 downvotes for no reason in just an hour? Is my question flawed? does it not contain description? is the English wrong? I'm really getting sick of this behavior

Comment: Since the actions are performed by the user itself in case of social engineering I would consider that case as mal user case not hacker.

Comment: The hacker only needs to hack the interface/gateway which gets the data from your distributed nodes and into the coherent blob which you pass to the user. And calling the social engineering attacker "not a hacker" is splitting hairs - it is still a security risk.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but your scenario looks very contrived to me. Find a real world example for such a system, and check how your question sounds when it is applied to that example.

Comment: Nor did I downvote you, but your question seems overly simplistic.  Security is a complex endeavor; I don't think you can come to any meaningful conclusions by observing any single metric, and we don't engage in idle speculation here.  If anything, more nodes increases the attack surface, making the system *less* secure.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: **No.**

Look around the world: as you surely know, currently millions of PCs or other network devices have been "hacked", they got malware installed and are incorporated into botnet farms, abused for spamming or other malware distribution, often without knowledge of their owner. Those computers are nothing but "nodes with independent storage", and the fact *"there is no single point where storage is available"* did not hinder hackers to make them targets.

Even if one creates such a network intentionally with the idea of better security in mind: for a huge network of nodes, one needs to use some common infrastructure, otherwise the thing becomes unmanageable. And when that infrastructure gets compromised, exploiting the security breaches can be automated. So the fallacy in this question is that each of the nodes needs to be "hacked" individually.

Answer (score 1):

I was taught that risk is a product of likelihood and outcome. With a single data store effort can be focused on securing that one store making a breach less likely. If one does occur, however, it will be more severe as all data is exposed. With distributed data a single-node breach will be less severe, but more likely since there is a greater surface to attack.

In theory good scripted devops practices should mean all nodes are equally configured and equally secure. Real life, however, would suggest this is seldom the case.